# Auto Generate id in sql php

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a reservation system where I have to generate an new id each time the user click on "New Reservation", this id is passed into hidden input as they are later on  used in other SQL tables that are linked to the reservation table. So the tables in questions are deposit, nights ect..

What I did first was to take the max value of the column id, and add 1 to it. The problem was that when multiple computer(people) where using it, the same id would be generated. The id is not inserted into the database until all information have been filled in.

Then what I did was that each time the user clicks on the button "Create new reservation" I would store that id in a temporary database and get the maxvalue of this table to generate another id. This works 2/3.

Do you have any idea on what would be the best way to get a unique id each time a reservation is created?

I am not asking for code, just a better logic.

Comment: use the primary key for storing ID, use Autoincrement to increment value automatically.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_last_insert_id.asp will get you the value of inserted row in MySQL

Comment: Why can't use auto increment id in mysql

Comment: Because there is two steps to the form. When the user enters the checkin/checkout dates. These values are used to generate fields for each nights so that we can enter a price for each nights. Then again I have to insert these fields into the nights table with the reservation id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`mysql_last_id`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.insert-id.php) to fetch the last inserted ID:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table (id, column1, column2) VALUES (NULL, 'Value #1', 'Value #2')");

printf("<p>ID of the previous record: %d.</p>", $mysqli->insert_id);
```

To add an auto-incremented id column, use this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD INDEX (`id`);
```

You can also choose the start of the next id with:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT=123;
```

Answer (score 4):

make the column id an auto increment, this will keep giving a new id each time a user clicks on new reservation [auto increment](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

the link above will show you how to do this....
with regards to the nights and reservation tables, you can copy the data from the nights table and add it to the reservation table using the insert into select statement [insert into](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

the link above will help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

One idea I've seen elsewhere is to create a number based on the current datetime (preferrably accurate to millisecond) AND a field unique to the computer/user account that creates the record.

Now, "based on" means you can customize this kind of function.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use SQL Auto-increment. You don't have to send a "id" in your form. When you're sending the form, just insert datas you received : MySQL will insert automatically the right value in "id". If you need to get back this id, you could use a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also view this video below which shows you exactly how to create a table and add a field as an auto increment: 
[Auto increment video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3FJN_2L87g)